# Compare two possibly null Java strings lexicographically

Tags: java, string, null

Is there a JDK method or [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that will compare two strings `A` and `B` *lexicographically* when either `A` or `B` (or both, or neither) may be `null`?

I don't much care whether `null` values come first or last in the ordering.

And note that I'm not looking for [`Objects#equals(Object a, Object b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-). I'm looking for a JDK method with the following prototype:

```
public int compare(String a, String b) ...
```

Or, alternatively, a JDK class along the lines of

```
public class StringComparatorWithNulls implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(String a, String b) {
        if (null == a) {
            return null == b ? 0 : -1;
        } else if (null == b) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return a.compareTo(b);
        }
    }
}
```

If there's nothing in the JDK that does this, something in a widely-used open-source library would also do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides the very useful [`Ordering`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) class ([more info](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/OrderingExplained)).  It has a fluent interface, and it extends `Comparator`, so you can use it anywhere you'd use a `Comparator`.

```
Comparator<String> nullSafeComparator = Ordering.<String>natural().nullsLast();
```

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for StringUtils or ObjectUtils, from common-lang3:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

With `public static boolean equals(CharSequence cs1,CharSequence cs2)`

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#equals(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)

Otherwise, if you want to compare, with:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#compare%28T,%20T%29

Answer (score 0):

The String `compareTo` does exactly that , you can add a null check for the string that would be calling this `compareTo` function, so that it handles `null` values -

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "bye";
System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s2));
>> -26
```

Your conditions would looks like -

```
if(s1 != null && s1.compareTo(s2) > 0)
```

The return of this method is an `int` which can be interpreted as follows:

- returns < 0 then the String calling the method is lexicographically
  first (comes first in a dictionary)
- returns == 0 then the two strings
  are lexicographically equivalent
- returns > 0 then the parameter
  passed to the compareTo method is lexicographically first.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Clearly OP could manually gate any calls to a non-null-safe comparison method; they want a way to avoid needing to gate everything.